# Login into facebook using oauth in python?

Tags: python, urllib3

I got the following link for a app
`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=SOME_NUMER_I_HAVE&redirect_uri=https://someSITE.com/fblogin&state=SOME_VALID_STATE`
I want to send the name and password, and get the cookie.

Does anyone know what the request would look like? 
(Or a library that takes care of this)

My setup, I'm trying to crawl a website, i need to login to this website to do so.

Answer (score 0):

a bit more info about your setup would be helpful.

If you are using Django I would recommend using `django-allauth` for social authentication.

Comment: My setup, I'm trying to crawl a website, i need to login to this website to do so.